# com.facebook.FacebookException: Attempted to use a Session that was not open

Tags: android, facebook

I integrated facebook sharing, It was working fine from last few days, but today just 2 hours before asking this question I am facing this issue.

I am using this code for Login :

```
  Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

// callback when session changes state
@Override
public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
  if (state.isOpened()) {

    // make request to the /me API
    Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

      // callback after Graph API response with user object
      @Override
      public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
        if (user != null) {
       
          Toast.makeText(ImagePagerActivity.this, user.getName()+" Logged In...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
      }
    }).executeAsync();
  }
}
});
publishFeedDialog();
```

The problem is in if() condition  which is always false, also I used `session.isOpened()` which is also returning false, I am confused why this happened.

I have declared INTERNET,ACCESSNETWORKSTATE, permission in manifest also

```
 <application>
 ..........
 ..........
 <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
 </application>
```

please help...

**EDIT**

This is the code of what I have implemented, you can see `onCreateOptionsMenu` , `onOptionsItemSelected`, `onActivityResult`, `publishFeedDialog`

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar_share_menu, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share1);
     
    
        return true;
    }
@Override

public boolean      onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
case R.id.menu_item_share1: // facebook item selected
Toast.makeText(this, "Menu Item 1 selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//start Facebook Login


Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

// callback when session changes state
@Override
public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
  if (state.isOpened()) {

    // make request to the /me API
    Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

      // callback after Graph API response with user object
      @Override
      public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
        if (user != null) {
       
          Toast.makeText(ImagePagerActivity.this, user.getName()+" Logged In...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
      }
    }).executeAsync();
  }
}
});
publishFeedDialog();

}
return true;
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new FacebookDialog.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Exception error, Bundle data) {
            Log.e("Activity", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
            Log.i("Activity", "Success!");
        }
    });
    
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt(STATE_POSITION, pager.getCurrentItem());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

private void publishFeedDialog() {
    
    Log.v("pos",""+pos);
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", ItemListApplication.names.get(pos).getItem());
    params.putString("caption", "Irrational beliefs");
    params.putString("description",ItemListApplication.names.get(pos).getDesc() );
    params.putString("link", "https://www.facebook.com/vivek.warde.3?ref=tn_tnmn");
    
    if(pos==0) params.putString("picture","http://i.imgur.com/lOIUcW2.jpg");
    else params.putString("picture",imageUrls[pos]);
    WebDialog feedDialog = (
        new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(this,
            Session.getActiveSession(),
            params))
        .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                FacebookException error) {
                if (error == null) {
                    // When the story is posted, echo the success
                    // and the post Id.
                    final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                    if (postId != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(ImagePagerActivity.this,
                            "Posted story, id: "+postId,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        // User clicked the Cancel button
                        Toast.makeText(ImagePagerActivity.this, 
                            "Publish cancelled", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                    // User clicked the "x" button
                    Toast.makeText(ImagePagerActivity.this, 
                        "Publish cancelled", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // Generic, ex: network error
                    Toast.makeText(ImagePagerActivity.this, 
                        "Error posting story", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        })
        .build();
    feedDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: At which line you are getting the error ? Have you tried opening session from cache `openActiveSessionFromCache`?

Comment: @Pr38y No, I don't know about that, by the way I use `openActiveSession` as u can see in the code

Comment: please post the code where you create your session

Comment: I edited my question, You can see my code..

Comment: have you specified sharing as one of the permissions in your facebook development dashboard?

Comment: Sorry? I didn't get you ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be many reasons dealing with this problem. You should check some of this:

I'm using this code for login via facebook:

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment {
   //... some code

   SessionStatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();

   public void login() {
       Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
       if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
           session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
       } else {
           Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), this, true, statusCallback);
       }
   }

   private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
       @Override
       public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
           if (exception != null) {
               handleException(exception);
           }
           if (state.isOpened()) {
               afterLogin();
           } else if (state.isClosed()) {
               afterLogout();
           }
        }
    }

}
```

If session wasn't opened you should open it for read (or for [publish](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Session/#openForPublish) if you need).

---

Check `meta-data` tag in AndroidManifest file, is there correct application id?

---

Often happens that error not inside android application but in facebook application settings. In facebook application's settings page should be correct package name, and you should add key hashes for you application (different for every release type, in most cases is debug and release).

[image: facebook android settings]

To get hash key you can run script

```
keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR_ALIAS -keystore PATH_TO_KEYSTORE_FILE | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

or you can get it inside code:

```
PackageInfo info;
try {
    info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("YOUR_APP_PACKAGE", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md;
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        String keyhash = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
        //string something is what you should paste as key hash
        Log.e("hash key", keyhash);
    }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
    Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("exception", e.toString());
}
```

---

In facebook application's settings page inside Status & Review tab you should make app public. Or if you still don't want to make it public, you should add roles for all users that can use your android application (inside Roles tab).

---

Also, if it don't help, try to debug method
`public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)`
There often normal messages why authorization wasn't successful

Comment: I am getting 2 different key hash by your 2 different methods, also tell me what should I write in "The Main Activity you want facebook to launch" ? I have added fb share button in every fragment..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24838476/package-name-class-name-of-facebook-app

Comment: I leaved that field empty, only wrote package name. About hashes, they  would be different for every release type. Means that for every new signature it will be different. IDE signing apk with debug key. But if you have release keystore which you will use to sign apk, you can add hash in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
 **generate keyhash from facebook api and then** 

 running this in to commandprompt/ terminal 

 keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR_ALIAS_NAME -keystore PATH_TO_KEYSTORE_FILE | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

in Android.Manifest file

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

in demofacebookLogin ( Activity file )

```
private Facebook facebook;
private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;


@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);

    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

 }

 public void loginToFacebook() {
    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        facebook.authorize(this,
                new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                new DialogListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // Function to handle cancel event
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        // Function to handle complete event
                        // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("access_token",
                                facebook.getAccessToken());
                        editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                facebook.getAccessExpires());
                        editor.commit();
                        getProfileInformation();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError error) {
                        // Function to handle error

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                        // Function to handle Facebook errors

                    }

                });
    }
}



    public void getProfileInformation() {
    mAsyncRunner.request("me", new RequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            Log.d("Profile", response);
            String json = response;
            try {
                JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);
                // getting name of the user
                facebook_FB_Id = profile.getString("id");
                facebook_username = profile.getString("name");
                // getting email of the user
                facebook_email = profile.getString("email");
                facebook_firstname = profile.getString("first_name");
                facebook_lastname = profile.getString("last_name");
                facebook_FbLink = profile.getString("link");

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        Log.i("", facebook_FB_Id + " == "
                                + facebook_username + " =="
                                + facebook_FbLink);

                        Intent startRegistrationTypeActivity = new Intent(
                                getContext(),
                                RegistrationTypeActivity.class);
                        startRegistrationTypeActivity.putExtra(
                                "facebook_FB_Id", facebook_FB_Id);
                        startRegistrationTypeActivity.putExtra(
                                "facebook_username", facebook_username);
                        startRegistrationTypeActivity.putExtra(
                                "facebook_email", facebook_email);
                        startRegistrationTypeActivity.putExtra(
                                "facebook_firstname", facebook_firstname);
                        startRegistrationTypeActivity.putExtra(
                                "facebook_lastname", facebook_lastname);
                        startRegistrationTypeActivity.putExtra(
                                "facebook_FbLink", facebook_FbLink);
                        startActivity(startRegistrationTypeActivity);

                    }

                });

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I dont want to get profile information , I want  to post image/text in facebook