# Flutter : how configure Facebook for authentication

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I have flutter app and using firebase and facebook login..

I am configuring Facebook and I am at step 5  "Associate Your Package Name and Default Class with Your App" from this document https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android

> Default Activity Class Name
>
> This is the fully qualified class name of the activity that handles deep linking such as com.example.app.DeepLinkingActivity. We use this when we deep link into your app from the Facebook app. You can also find this in your Android Manifest.

What does that above statement means? Is there something else I need to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official facebook documentation is not created for any cross platform,
Please follow [those](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_login) steps if you are using `flutter_facebook_login` plugin.

Comment: I am following that plugin in instruction and it  says to do this  ===> "This assumes that you've done the "Associate Your Package Name and Default Class with Your App" and "Provide the Development and Release Key Hashes for Your App" in the the Facebook Login documentation for Android site."

Comment: Are you using google sign in along with facebook sign in as well?

Comment: Yes. I am using both ... Google login is working.,.

Comment: Okay so try this link, it can be helpful to you.

In default activity name please provide activity name which is given by flutter package.


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24838476/package-name-class-name-of-facebook-app